# Using basic HTML to render and check

Tags: python, html, mvc, pyramid

I am a newbie and I am using basic HTML to render and check. No JSON at the moment. With that said, I’m having a hard time conceptualizing organization of a group of matching series (e.g. a series that falls under a given number, say 1) into a single link that expands into the subseries (say, 1a, 1b, 1c...) for a detailed list; this second portion would be found on a separate page.

Ideally (here is a sketch):

HTML page showing all the series:

```
<a href= ‘MicroSeries 1’>
```

This link opens to a separate HTML page with the **matching** **subseries**:

Subseries 1a, 1b, 1c, 1d

```
<a href= 'MicroSeries 2'>
```

Same logic as above.

I think my idea is the way to attack the problem, but please feel free to recommend a better approach. I have a former question that reveals more of what I initially created: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35441874/looping-through-a-list-of-object-values-remove-duplicates-and-return-unique-va). However, I believe I may have attacked the issue incorrectly. I also think I've confused myself pretty bad.

As of right now, having a single link that opens up to the subseries does not exist for each microseries without manual code (as you one can tell below).

Using: Python 2.7, Pyramid (JINJA2 templates), SQLAlchemy

Route (**init.py**):

```
config.add_route('assessments', '/assessments')
config.add_route('assessment', '/assessments/{id:\d+}')
config.add_route('view_subseries', '/assessments/{microseries}')
```

View Code:

```
@view_config(route_name='assessments', request_method='GET', renderer='templates/unique_assessments.jinja2')
def view_unique_microseries_group(request):

    all_assessments = api.retrieve_assessments() #all assessments in a list
    assessments_by_microseries = {} #dictonary

    for x in all_assessments:
        if x.microseries in assessments_by_microseries:
            print("Already seen this microseries: %s" % x.microseries)
        else:
            assessments_by_microseries[x.microseries] = x

    unique_assessments = sorted(assessments_by_microseries.values()) #.values() method to get the, err, values of the dict.
    print 'unique_assessments:', unique_assessments

    #a = HTTPSeeOther(location=request.route_url('view_subseries'))

    return {'logged_in': logged_in_userid, 'unique_assessments': unique_assessments}

@view_config(route_name='view_subseries', request_method='GET', renderer='templates/assessments.jinja2')
def view_microseries_subseries(request):

    all_assessments = api.retrieve_assessments() #all assessments in a list
    series1 = []
    series2 = []
    series3 = []
    series4 = []
    series5 = []

    for x in all_assessments:
        if x.microseries ==1:
            series1.append(x)
            #print 'series1 ', series1
        elif x.microseries ==2:
            series2.append(x)
            #print 'series2', series2
        elif x.microseries ==3:
            series3.append(x)
            #print 'series3', series3
        elif x.microseries ==4:
            series4.append(x)
            #print 'series4', series4
        elif x.microseries ==5:
            series5.append(x)
            #print 'series5', series5
        else:
            raise HTTPNotFound

    return {'logged_in': logged_in_userid, 'series1': series1, 'series2': series2, 'series3':series3, 'series4':series4, 'series5':series5, 'all_assessments': all_assessments}
```

HTML for showing all subseries (assessments.jinja2):

```html
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead class='tablename'>
            <h2>Microseries subseries</h2>
            <tr>
                <td>  </td>
                <td> SubSeries </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
    {% for a in series1 %} # needs to grab a matching subseries... maybe used hidden instead ? this does not work for each set

    {% if a in all_assessments %}
            <td><a href="{{ '/assessments/%s'%a.microseries|urlencode }}"><button type='button' class='btn outline btn-primary'>Play</button></a></td>
            <td>{{ a }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially when you're just starting out it would be actually good to
use Python 3, but even if you're not doing that compatibility with it
would be a good idea anyway, e.g. use `print(x)` instead of `print x`.

Next, the grouping code in `view_microseries_subseries` is clearly
repetitive.  Every time you encounter such a pattern where you create
additional variables with a counter suffix (`variable42` etc.) try to
switch to a different representation like the dictionary in
`view_unique_microseries_group`, or maybe a list of lists with direct
addressing by index.  I also don't get why specifically `HTTPNotFound`
is raised.

With a bit of cleanup I'd suggest the following:

```
@view_config(route_name='view_subseries', request_method='GET', renderer='templates/assessments.jinja2')
def view_microseries_subseries(request):
    all_assessments = api.retrieve_assessments()
    series = [[] for _ in xrange(5)]

    for x in all_assessments:
        if not 1 <= x.microseries <= 5:
            raise HTTPNotFound
        series[x.microseries].append(x)

    return {'logged_in': logged_in_userid, 'series': series, 'all_assessments': all_assessments}
```

In the HTML, I don't quite understand why only `series1` is used, while
more than that is computed in the route handler.

Apart from that it looks okay to me.

Comment: Thank you ferada. I heard Python 3 was buggy so I didn't want to jump onto a language that is still being worked on. But it seems that Python 3 is not supported. I want to start using JSON and JS to check instead of static HTML as it feel limiting.